# How to create a folder on the file system if it does not exist when saving files

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Given the below XQuery code generating paths and saving files based on data in  MarkLogic database, how can I create the file system folder if it does not exist without getting an exception?

```
for $doc in collection("http://example.com/stuff")
let $folderName := name($doc/Envelope/*[1]) 
let $folderPath := concat("c:\temp\", $folderName, "\")
let $fileName := concat($doc/Envelope/*[1]/*:Code/text(), ".xml")
let $fullPath := concat($folderPath, $fileName)  

(: Create the folder at $folderPath if it does not exist :)

return xdmp:save($fullPath,$doc)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK there is no "folder exists" function, confusingly `filesystem-file-exists` actually works for folders too, so the answer would be:

```
for $doc in collection("http://example.com/stuff")
let $folderName := name($doc/Envelope/*[1]) 
let $folderPath := concat("c:\temp\", $folderName, "\")
let $fileName := concat($doc/Envelope/*[1]/*:Code/text(), ".xml")
let $fullPath := concat($folderPath, $fileName)  

let $_ := if(xdmp:filesystem-file-exists($folderPath)) then () else xdmp:filesystem-directory-create($folder)

return xdmp:save($fullPath,$doc)
```